# How to get a JanusgraphGraph Instance from a remote janusgraph connection

Tags: java, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I want to use the management API in my java based application to dynamically create Schemas and to use indices. But I cant find a solution to get the JanusGraph - Graph instance from my remote connection. But I need it to get the management instance from it (by calling `graph.openManagement()`, which then can be used to manage schemas and indices.

Im already using tinkerpop gremlin to create queries. But when I call `g.getGraph()` it retruns an empty graph which I can't even set graph variables on. Everything else works just fine with the source traversal.

The examples in the janusgraph documentation all assumes one already has the graph in hand: https://docs.janusgraph.org/schema/

Answer (score 2):

It's important to try to understand the [different mechanisms for connecting to graphs](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#connecting-gremlin) with TinkerPop. Getting clarity around the definitions and limitations of each is important to have a conversation about what you're asking.

With "embedded mode" you instantiate a `JanusGraph` instance directly in the JVM, meaning that you have access to all its APIs just as you would any other class. One of these APIs is the Management API that you are asking about.

With "remote mode" you instantiate a connection to Gremlin Server using TinkerPop objects (i.e. like `EmptyGraph`) which know nothing about JanusGraph APIs. You can think of this akin to an interface where you can only use the functions of the interface but not the implementation itself. In this mode, you cannot access the Management API as you have found.

The only way you can access those APIs remotely is by way of [script submission](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-java-scripts). In this way you submit a Groovy script to the server and it is applied to a `JanusGraph` object running in embedded mode on the server. Recall that in embedded mode, you get access to all of the available methods on the `JanusGraph` object itself. In this way you can call `graph.openManagement()` and make the appropriate calls to create indices and the like on the resulting object.

Comment: Thx. So the only way to use the management api is by creating an "embedded janusgraph instance" inside of my application? But isnt that really bad for seperating responibilities? Because for some core feature like indexing and schema management, I need the management API

Comment: well, again, there are two options: embedded or remote with scripts. if you look into the janusgraph architecture i don't think you'll find embedding a bad practice necessarily. a `JanusGraph` instance in the context i'm referring to here is the literally the `JanusGraph` class which depending on the backend you've chosen is essentially a client connection to a Cassandra or Hbase cluster or the like.